# How do I redraw certain parts of this polygon in a polygon?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have a polygon with certain data, and I need, to repaint them in a different color according to the Area column, and leave the rest unchanged.

I found how to recolor the entire polygon using `QColor`, but not a specific part.

With the code below, I'm repainting the entire polygon, but not a specific part

```
lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("output")[0]
rndr = lyr.renderer()                   # object to change rendering
rndr.dump()  
sym = rndr.symbol()                     # object to change the symbology of layer
syms = sym[0]                           # use first layer in QGIS tree
syms.setColor(QColor("blue"))                 # remove the fill colour
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to create graduated or categorized symbologies?

Comment: With `pyqgis`-tag, please insert some code

Comment: @Erik well, if I correctly understood the essence of categorized symbologies, then most likely yes, we go through the entire polygon and compare whether it satisfies the desired value or not, if yes we will repaint, no we will leave.

Comment: It's really confusing to refer to symbolization as "redraw certain parts of this polygon in a polygon" -- it's not a 'redraw' *per se* but a different rendering process.

Comment: Are you mixing up the terms "layer" and "polygon" perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To render features in different colors depending on an attribute value, you need to use a renderer type other than single symbol renderer.
This would be a good use case for a Rule-Based Renderer.
In this instance, you would set up 2 rules and associate a legend label and color with each rule. The rules are based on expressions, and these are the basis on which the layer features are styled.

You can use and modify the code snippet below:

```py
lyr = iface.activeLayer()

rules = (#...Label......Expression.......Color 
            ('Area 15', "Area = 15", QColor('blue')), 
            ('Other areas', "Area != 15", QColor('#cdb9a5')) 
        )
                
# create a new rule-based renderer
symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(lyr.geometryType())
renderer = QgsRuleBasedRenderer(symbol)
# get the "root" rule
root_rule = renderer.rootRule()

for label, expression, color in rules:
    # create a clone (i.e. a copy) of the default rule
    rule = root_rule.children()[0].clone()
    # set the label, expression and color
    rule.setLabel(label)
    rule.setFilterExpression(expression)
    rule.symbol().setColor(color)
    # set the scale limits if they have been specified
    root_rule.appendChild(rule)

# delete the default rule
root_rule.removeChildAt(0)
# apply the renderer to the layer
lyr.setRenderer(renderer)
# refresh the layer on the map canvas
lyr.triggerRepaint()
```

Attribute table of my test layer:

[image]

Result:

[image]

By modifying the rule expressions, you can alter the result.

E.g. using the rules:

```py
rules = (
            ('Areas 3, 29 & 31', "Area IN (3, 29, 31)", QColor('blue')),
            ('Other areas', "Area NOT IN (3, 29, 31)", QColor('#cdb9a5')),
        )
```

Result:

[image]

Using the rules:

```py
rules = ( 
            ('Areas 30-40', "Area > 29 AND Area < 40", QColor('blue')), 
            ('Other areas', "Area < 30 OR Area > 39", QColor('#cdb9a5')) 
        )
```

Result:

[image]